# Trigger a task from TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: airflow

Is there any way to trigger a particular task of dependent dag using TriggerDagRunOperator.
I want a dag once successfull should trigger a particular task of another dag.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: that particular task is the initial task of the second DAG?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
No, It is the second task of the second DAG.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. If you think about it, how would you do with the 1st task when the 2nd is executed? My recommendation is to change your pipeline a bit and trigger the full dag from another dag. Then, you can add conditional task at the beginning who decides what is next.